# R error: join_cols() / join_vert(): number of columns must be the same

Tags: c++, r

I have a problem fitting instrumental variable models with covariates with the bayesm package in R. Adding covariates results in the error message :
"error: join_cols() / join_vert(): number of columns must be the same"

The error stems from the external function 'rivDP_rcpp_loop.cpp' called via Rcpp. I am however not skilled enough to handle the problem on R level.

I constructed an example based on the function example which results in the error on my machine.

```
##
## simulate scaled log-normal errors and run
##
set.seed(66)
k=10
delta=1.5
Sigma=matrix(c(1,.6,.6,1),ncol=2)
N=1000
tbeta=4
set.seed(66)
scalefactor=.6
root=chol(scalefactor*Sigma)
mu=c(1,1)
##
## compute interquartile ranges
##
ninterq=qnorm(.75)-qnorm(.25)
error=matrix(rnorm(100000*2),ncol=2)
error=t(t(error)+mu)
Err=t(t(exp(error))-exp(mu+.5*scalefactor*diag(Sigma)))
lnNinterq=quantile(Err[,1],prob=.75)-quantile(Err[,1],prob=.25)
##
## simulate data
##
error=matrix(rnorm(N*2),ncol=2)%*%root
error=t(t(error)+mu)
Err=t(t(exp(error))-exp(mu+.5*scalefactor*diag(Sigma)))
#
# scale appropriately  
Err[,1]=Err[,1]*ninterq/lnNinterq
Err[,2]=Err[,2]*ninterq/lnNinterq
z=matrix(runif(k*N),ncol=k)
x=z%*%(delta*c(rep(1,k)))+Err[,1]
y=x*tbeta+Err[,2]
w<-matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=10)

# set intial values for MCMC
Data = list(); Mcmc=list()
Data$z<-cbind(z,w);  Data$x=x; Data$y=y; Data$w<-w

# start MCMC and keep results
Mcmc$maxuniq=100
Mcmc$R=R
end=Mcmc$R
begin=100

out=rivDP(Data=Data,Mcmc=Mcmc)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this on our cluster machines, but it did not work and still produced the same error. From contacting the author of the package, I learned that changing some algorithms to Rcpp is the source of the problem and a new release of the package planned for September.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and have contacted the package maintainer for clarification. In the mean time I was able to get the rivDP() function to work by downloading the version 2.2-5 from 2012. Make sure to install Rtools first (from here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and then run the following code:

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/bayesm/bayesm_2.2-5.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")

library(bayesm)
```